# Menu shows right in Chrome, but not in Firefox

Tags: html, css, background, cross-browser

I'm having a problem with a nav bar in my site. It works in chrome, but something weird happens in firefox and I have no idea what it is...

In Firefox, the dark bar menu background doesn't show. It is transparent for some reason:

[image: Firefox]

In Chrome is works as expected:

[image: Chrome]

My sites wrapper has opacity 0.9, but I don't think this has anything to do with the menu not showing, since it shows on chrome...

Here is the HTML and CSS for my header: http://jsfiddle.net/Xdc9F/

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <header>
            <h1>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/z3Y7cmW.png" alt="" />
                        </a>
                    </h1>

    </header>
</div>
<!-- closing header -->
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Sobre Nós</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Localização</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Contato</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu, .menu ul, .menu ul li, .menu ul li a {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    font-family:'Capriola', sans-serif;
}
.menu:before, .menu:after, .menu > ul:before, .menu > ul:after {
    content:'';
    display: table;
}
.menu:after, .menu > ul:after {
    clear: both;
}
.menu {
    zoom:1;
    height: 69px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/XnKK9WL.png) repeat-x center bottom;
    margin-top: 100px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.menu ul {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/elYFBsn.png) repeat-x 0px 4px;
    opacity: 1;
    height: 69px;
}
.menu ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
.menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    height: 37px;
    padding: 22px 30px 0;
    margin: 4px 2px 0;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    font-weight: 400;
    opacity: .9;
}
.menu ul li:first-child a {
    margin: 4px 2px 0 0;
}
.menu ul li a:hover, .menu ul li.active a {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/jCkWOJx.png) center bottom;
    display: block;
    height: 37px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 26px;
    color: #004f7c;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .55);
    opacity: 1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I just pasted the header section, if you need the whole page code just tell me.

Comment: Here is how it is shown in chrome  http://i.stack.imgur.com/GdIJp.png  << here it looks kinda ok, the dark background and stuff is showing, just the blue border at the bottom inst, I dunno why too...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Everything works great for me. Probably you have done something wrong with the rest html or CSS.

The blue border is because of this rule:

background: `url("http://i.imgur.com/XnKK9WL.png") repeat-x scroll center bottom transparent;`

If you delete there isn't blue border

Comment: Oh, I just deleted the wrapper's div and it worked. Weird, Still don't know what was going on but oh welll atleast it is sorted